# Microsoft NDES server not supporting latest cryptography algorithm for SCEP

Tags: active-directory, certificate, scep

I have a Network Device Enrollment Service running on a MS Windows Server 2016 machine. I want to use it for certificate signing requests with SCEP. However, when I query the capabilities of the server it returns that `3DES` is the strongest cipher algorithm that it supports. The client library is expecting to use `AES`.

I've tried multiple things to configure the server to support AES, including changing some registry settings:

```
[HLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\<Your CA Common Name>\EncryptionCSP]
EncryptionAlgorithm (0x6603 -> 0x6610)
CNGEncryptionAlgorithm (3DES -> AES)
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect. Can anyone shed light on what I'm missing?